# insert statement show 1 row created but data is not insert (script)

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus, toad

I am using Run SQL Command Line to insert my data, the script ask below.

```
INSERT INTO USERMASTER (USERID,USERPWD,USERNAME,USERPOSITION,USERACCESSRIGHTS,USERSTATUS,CREATEUSERID) VALUES ('admin','nVzfJ0sOjj/EFU700exL6A==','Admin','Administrator','Non-Administrator','1', 'admin');
```

but when I open my database by using toad and log in the user and see, the data is not insert into the table. May I know where is the place goes wrong?

image below is the output in sql command.
[image]

Comment: Did you `COMMIT` the insert? You login credentials owner/schema is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about commit.
Is autocommit on?

or add 'commit' after your insert statement

Comment: yeS! edit the answer add on 'commit' after insert statement. Thanks!